# Generating Data using Python - Time Data

Tags: python-3.x, timestamp

I need to generate time stamp in the following sequence;

```
    From  To    Time1      Time2      Time3
    A     EE   9:30 AM    10:45 AM   10:50 AM
    B     FF   9:40 AM    10:35 AM   11:00 AM
    C     GG   9:55 AM    10:20 AM   11:15 AM
    D     HH  10:05 AM    10:10 AM   11:25 AM
```

The catch is I need to generate the columns **Time2** and **Time3**, I do know it is possible to generate random timestamp using *randrange* and *timedelta* using **Python**. What, I am not able to understand is the possibility of creating a dataset, with a frequency as exactly as given above.

The assumption here is that on reaching the last station the train takes a 5- 10 mins halt before proceeding on a return trip, and also it takes same time to commute between the stations as given above in column **Time1**.

I have the sample data in .csv file and it contains a list of **n** number of stations.

Any help would be really appreciable.